# Why the image doesn't appear in the browser in the react project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the react project and the problem is when I open the website on my computer the image doesn't appear in the browser so I want to know If the problem is in the path of the image or in the extension of the image
the code is in javascript

here's the path of the file
src
1-components
*Main.js
*Navbar.js
2-images
*reactjs-icon.png

in Navbar.js file :

```
 import React from "react"
export default function Navbar() {
    return (
        <nav>
            <img src="../images/reactjs-icon.png" alt="my"/>

            <h3>ReactFacts</h3>
            <h4>React Course - Project 1</h4>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

in css file

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #21222A;
  height: 90px;
  padding: 30px 25px;
}
nav > h3, nav > h4 {
  margin: 0;
}

nav > img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

[here's what is appear in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tk5hn.png)
and here's the files structure
[and here's the files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxopr.png)

Comment: It's definitely the path problem. Can you share your folder structure ?

Comment: ok can you please tell me the correct path?

Comment: Please share your folder structure and assuming the image is in some public folder absolute path may be best

Comment: `localhost:3000`.   A path of `../images` is not going to exist.

Comment: Is the web server root in `src` as you seem to be expecting, or is it in `public` instead?  I'd expect the latter.  Or perhaps both are used to create a `dist` (or similar) folder from which the result is actually served?  Either way, I wouldn't expect anything in `src` to be accessible via the web server.  At least it very much shouldn't be set up that way in production.

Comment: it is in src folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the conventional way :

In order to access the images directly and use relative paths and for that you need to actually keep your images in public directory.

```
|-- public 
|     |-- images 
|           |-- my_image.png
```

So in normal scenario where i want to load an image which is present in images folder.

```
  <img src="/images/my_image.png"  alt="my image" />
```

Here the image will get rendered as all files in public are treated statically.

The react way :

In react you may want to render some images which are not present in public folder then you need to import image(s) and in src send the alias or variable.

```
import logo from'../images/react_logo.png';


class NavBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <nav className="nav" style={nbStyle}>
        <div className="container">
          <img  src={logo} alt="logo"/>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

> Now react knows that the image needs to be exposed to public url and will handle the image by making it available .

Comment: I just added a picture with the file structure

Comment: can you please check the last image that I added ?

Comment: @shereen gamal Just checked, you just need to import the image first inorder to use. Or for making it easier you could always create images folder in public and then use absolute or relative paths

Comment: can you please illustrate more ?

Comment: thanks a lot  I understood the problem @Sanmeet

Comment: @shereen gamal Check the answer now i made it more elaborate. Welcome :-)